# Convert script from csh to sh?

Tags: bash, csh

I'm trying to convert `*.csh` script to `*.sh`. I am having trouble specifically with this block.

```
foreach f (tmp*)
echo $f
set zid = `grep db $f`
if !(-e "$zid".mol2) then
set filename = "$zid".mol2
else foreach n (`seq -w 1 11247`)
if !(-e "$zid"_"$n".mol2) then
set filename = "$zid"_"$n".mol2     break
endif
end
endif
mv -v $f $filename
end
```

I tried changing it to this:

```
 for f in tmp*
 do
 echo $f
 set zid = `grep db $f`
 if ! [-e "$zid".mol2] ; then
 set filename = "$zid".mol2
 else for n in `seq -w 1 11247`
 if ! [-e "$zid"_"$n".mol2] ; then
 set filename = "$zid"_"$n".mol2
 break
 fi
 done
 fi
 mv -v $f $filename
 done
```

But I get this error:

```
 ./scripts/ex01.sh: line 31: syntax error near unexpected token `if'
 ./scripts/ex01.sh: line 31: `if ! [-e "$zid"_"$n".mol2] ; then'
```

Also I have a problem with this part `cat $VSTROOT/db.mol2 | csplit -ftmp -n4 -ks - '%^@.TRIPOS.MOLECULE%'      '/^@.TRIPOS.MOLECULE/' '{*}'`

Where I preset `VSTROOT=pwd`, but when executed it tells me `cat: pwd/db.mol2: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Bash (logical negation)[https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html] is !=

Comment: `VSTROOT=$(pwd)` to call the command, or use the builtin variable `VSTROOT=$PWD`

Comment: Also, you can paste shell code into http://www.shellcheck.net for help with syntax and best practice

Comment: It looks like you misspelt `[ -e` as `[-e`.  Run your code throught `shellcheck` (or use the online service) before resorting to the wisdom of the Internet.  Oh, and you missed out a `do`, but the error message is already telling you about that.

Comment: I tried `VSTROOT=$(pwd)` and it still doesn't work. It seems to work with every thing from echo to ls, but cd just isn't working. Is there anyway I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without really commenting on the propriety of this script, but just addressing the syntactic issues, the primary errors are incorrect assignments of variables, a missing "do", misuse/abuse of the `[` command, and a few other details.  Try:

```
    for f in tmp*
    do
        echo "$f"
        zid=$(grep db "$f")
        if ! [ -e "$zid".mol2 ] ; then
            filename="$zid".mol2
        else 
            for n in $(seq -w 1 11247)
            do
                if ! [ -e "$zid"_"$n".mol2 ] ; then
                    filename="$zid"_"$n".mol2
                    break
                 fi
            done
        fi
        mv -v "$f" "$filename"
    done
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash doesn't like spaces and it loves brackets around vars ... Anyway, it would look something like this (untested code) :

```
for f in tmp* ; do
    echo $f
    zid=$(grep db $f)
    if ! [ -e "$zid".mol2 ] ; then
        filename="$zid".mol2
     else
        for ((n=1; n<11248; n++ )) ; do
            if ! [ -e "$zid"_"$n".mol2 ] ; then
                filename="$zid"_"$n".mol2
                break
            fi
        done
    fi
    mv -v $f $filename
done
```